# What's the proper flow for creating the aggregate root and it's child objects (entities)?

Tags: php, domain-driven-design

I'm refactoring my data driven design towards domain driven, and I have a few questions of how the code should be structured

I have a `User entity`

```
namespace Planner\Domain\Entities;

class UserEntity {
    private $userId;

    private $weight;
    private $height;

    public function __construct(int $id, float $weight, float $height){
        $this->userId = $id;
        ...
    }
}
```

I also have a `Settings entity` which should be created along with the user object creation.

```
namespace Planner\Domain\Entities;

class SettingsEntity {
    private $id;

    private $userId;

    private $darkTheme;

    public function __construct(int $id, int $userId, bool $darkTheme){
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->userId = $userId;
        $this->darkTheme = $darkTheme;
    }
}
```

The Settings object cannot exist without the User, so the settingsEntity should be managed by the User entity. Meaning, the User entity isn't just an entity, it should be an aggregate root.

At the current moment, when the user clicks to "create account" the App makes an API request to `example.com/user/save`, the controller action sends the request object to `Planner\Application\Services\UserService` save method.

```
namespace Planner\Application\Services;

use Planner\Domain\Entities\UserEntity;
use Planner\Domain\Entities\SettingsEntity;
use Planner\Domain\Repositories\UserRepository;
use Planner\Application\Services\SettingsService;

class UserService {

    public function __construct(UserRepository $repo, SettingsService $settings){
        $this->userRepository = $repo;
        $this->settingsService = $settings;

    }

    public function save($request){
        $user = new UserEntity(...);

        $settings = new SettingsEntity(...);

        if(!$this->userRepository->save($user) || !$this->settingsRepository->save($settings)){
            throw new UserCreationFailedException();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, I don't know if the User entity and Settings Entity should be created in one go from a (theoretically speaking as I don't have a User Aggragate Root, just an User Entity) User Aggregate root or if the current way is valid.

I have other entities that will need to be created at the same time... same as the settings object, do I just add them to the `if` check in the UserService save method (above code) or should it all be under the user Aggregate, for example:

```
namespace Planner\Domain;

class User extends AggragateRoot {

    public function __construct(UserRepository $repository){
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    public function createAccount($request){
        $user = new UserEntity(...$request);
        $settings = new SettingsEntity(...$user);

        $this->repository->save($user, $settings);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the top-level entities are aggregate roots. In your current design the `UserEntity` and the `SettingsEntity` are effectively aggregate roots (AR)s. ARs are transactional & consistency boundaries. The AR's role is to make sure that invariants related to the data they encapsulate are never broken, even through concurrency.

ARs should be designed as small as possible, because they prevent concurrent modifications of the data they protect. In order to benefit from the AR pattern you must strive to respect the AR as a transactional boundary and therefore try to only modify a single AR per transaction for most use cases (there could be exceptions). That rule doesn't apply when creating ARs though, because concurrency conflicts shouldn't be common at creation.

There's 2 potential designs that are obvious here and the right one depends on the actual business invariants and the compromises you want to make.

1. `User` and `Settings` have cross-invariants, meaning the invariants of `User` may depend on the state of `Settings` and vice-versa. In that case `User` and `Settings` must be part of the same consistency boundary. You'd most likely have `User` as the AR and `Settings` as an entity living within `User`.
2. `User` and `Settings` can evolve independently (except for their creation). In that case you would most likely want to keep `User` and `Settings` as their own independent AR, but create both in the same transaction (or not -- eventual consistency). Note that it's often elegant to have a factory method on an AR to create another.

   ```
   transaction {
        user = new User(…)
        settings = user.initSettings(...)
        userRepository.save(user);
        settingsRepository.save(settings);
   }
   ```

   From that point forward, `User` and `Settings` would be modified in distinct transactions.

PS: I would recommend dropping technical prefixes such as "Entity". Language is key to DDD and I doubt domain experts uses the word "UserEntity" (perhaps not even "User") nor "SettingsEntity" in their language.

Answer (score 1):

It depends if it's a new user or not.

If it's an existing User, One way to approach it is to use a repository to "hydrate" the user and settings from the storage. Then modify.

If it's a new user, you could use a factory to instantiate the Aggregate root (User Entity) and use a factory method that fits the UL to generate the settings from the inputs.

Once you have your user object, send it to your repository for persistence.